# JSON can't read value of field [Vue.js]

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

```
 data() {
    return {
        message: null,
        currentMessage: 'test',
   }
```

I have function

```
valueOfMeasurement(measurement) {
        if (this.message instanceof Uint8Array) {
            var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
            this.currentMessage = enc.decode(this.message);
            console.log("current message: ");
            console.log(this.currentMessage); //only this console.log returns value
            console.log(this.currentMessage["field" + measurement.fieldId]);
            console.log(this.currentMessage["field1"]);
            console.log(this.currentMessage[0]["field1"]);
            return currentMessage["field" + measurement.fieldId];
        } 

        else 
         return this.message.feeds[0]["field" + measurement.fieldId];
    }
```

Short explanation of function:

I call it in `<child-component :value=valueOfMeasurement(measurement)></child-component>` to pass it value to child component.
`measurement` is JSON object that I use to identify which component and data is used,

`measurement.fieldId` have values 1,2,3...

`message` is `JSON array` which I get via `REST` and `MQTT` Api.I use `REST` to get current values (because `MQTT` has few minutes delay before reading any data,  and then `MQTT` to get new values without refreshing page.  I call `REST` first to get initial value  in `beforeMounted` and then my `message` have value:

```
  {
   "channel":{
      "id":1500203,
      "name":"PlastenikDemo",
      "description":"Demo kanal za sistem nadzora plastenika",
      "latitude":"0.0",
      "longitude":"0.0",
      "field1":"TemperaturaVazduha",
      "field2":"VlaznostVazduha",
      "field3":"TemperaturaZemlje",
      "field4":"VlaznostZemlje",
      "field5":"IntenzitetSvjetla",
      "field7":"VerzijaPrograma",
      "field8":"Vrijemems",
      "created_at":"2021-09-08T07:37:06Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-09-28T12:51:38Z",
      "last_entry_id":17901
   },
   "feeds":[
      {
         "created_at":"2021-11-28T00:11:38Z",
         "entry_id":17901,
         "field1":"16.40000",
         "field2":"45.50000",
         "field3":"16.06250",
         "field4":"5.20000",
         "field5":"49.79300",
         "field7":"1",
         "field8":"390267909"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is used in `else` part of function above, and it pass values normally.

After that, in my `mounted()`  I call another functions that get message from `MQTT` protocol. It has delay of about 5 mins before it get any message from this protocol. Now this is where problems begin. If I put `<div> {{this.message}} </div>` I get normal message from `MQTT` as JSON object:

```
    {
   "channel_id":1500203,
   "created_at":"2021-11-28T02:09:39Z",
   "entry_id":17924,
   "field1":"16.30000",
   "field2":"45.50000",
   "field3":"15.93750",
   "field4":"5.20000",
   "field5":"49.79300",
   "field6":null,
   "field7":"1",
   "field8":"397348953",
   "latitude":null,
   "longitude":null,
   "elevation":null,
   "status":null
}
```

But if I `console.log(this.message)` inside function `valueOfMeasurement(measurement)` I get arrays of `Uint8Array`. That's why I did `this.currentMessage = enc.decode(this.message);` and when I `console.log(this.currentMessage)` I get normal `JSON object` but, in same function, line under it, I try `console.log(this.currentMessage["field1"]` and I get `undefined`.

Also, in my `<div>this.currentMessage</div>`  when I restart page I get `test` on my screen, which is ok, because I set it in `data`, but when code gets into this function `valueOfMeasurement(measurement)` and into `if-loop` I get error in console `Reference error: currentMessage is not defined` and in same console, next 5 lines are:

`current message:`

```
 {
   "channel_id":1500203,
   "created_at":"2021-11-28T02:09:39Z",
   "entry_id":17924,
   "field1":"16.30000",
   "field2":"45.50000",
   "field3":"15.93750",
   "field4":"5.20000",
   "field5":"49.79300",
   "field6":null,
   "field7":"1",
   "field8":"397348953",
   "latitude":null,
   "longitude":null,
   "elevation":null,
   "status":null
}
```

`undefined`
`undefined`
`undefined`.

These 5 `console.logs` are from `valueOfMeasurement(measurement)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is that enc.decode() returns string and not JSON, so I need to add `JSON.parse`

```
 if (this.message instanceof Uint8Array) {
            var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
            this.currentMessage = JSON.parse(enc.decode(this.message));
            
            return this.currentMessage["field" + measurement.fieldId];
        }
```